# Display in VIEW of One to One relation in Laravel Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I am here again with a trouble understanding the correct way of doing Laravel Relationships

I have this User Model

```
 public function concessionaire()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Concessionaire', 'meternum', 'meternum');
}
```

and Concessionaire Model

```
 public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTO('App\User', 'meternum', 'meternum');
}
```

But when I try to display it in my view. the concessionaire data fields does not display..

In my Controller I have this

```
$dataUser = User::where('usertype', '=', 'concessionaire')
                ->with('concessionaire')
                ->get();
    return view('admin.concessionaire',compact('dataUser'));
```

in my View

```
@foreach($dataUser as $User)
<td>
{{ $User->clark }}
</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Try fetching simple data

Comment: I already tried but the data fields on the concessionaire tables does not displayed on my controller

Comment: Is simple data displaying there?

Comment: it displays onlye the data on the 1st table nothing on the 2nd table

Comment: Can you please show your database structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first please check the foreign and local key's are correct in the relation function implementation. after that try dumb the data like

```
dd($dataUser )
```

and check whether the user model's relations attributes actually contains the relationship model if its not empty you can access the property like

```
$User->concessionaire->property
```

if the relations attributes shows empty then you might have put incorrect local or foreign keys in the relationship implementation function.

you should follow

```
$this->hasOne(Relation::class, 'foreign key in related model', 'local key')
```

Comment: It appears on DD but how can I get those values? `@foreach($dataUser as $User)
<td>
{{ $User->clark }}
</td>
@endforeach`

Comment: if it appears in DD then you can access in the way `@foreach($dataUser as $User)
<td>
{{ $User->concessionaire->property_name }}
</td>
@endforeach`

Answer (score -1):

```
function concessionaire()
 {
   return $this->hasOne( Concessionaire::class, 'user_id', 'id');
 }
```

Now you can access the property with

```
@foreach($dataUser as $User)
  <td>
    {{ $User->concessionaire->property }}
 </td>
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it doesnt work also :( I get error of "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: I also updated my work with your comment but still not working :(