# one to one relationship between two table in laravel by controllers

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have a table user table and want to join address table with user table primary key which is foreign key in address table.

Please let me know how I can perform one to one relationship between both of these table by controllers in Laravel and display them in view.

Comment: Welcome to SO... First read Laravel docs to understand the basics then attempt yourself, if you still get stuck post the code of your attempt here on SO to get help. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by adding an eloquent relationship in Model files.

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the phone associated with the user.
     */
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Address::class);
    }
}
```

Address.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user that owns the phone.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Note: Both of the above models will assume by default `user_id` as a foreign key in the Address table.

To access this relationship in Controller,

```
$address = User::find($user_id)->address;
```

To access this relationship in View,

```
{{ $user->address->pincode }}
```

Since this is a Duplicate post, you can refer to this
[Display in VIEW of One to One relation in Laravel Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49093987/display-in-view-of-one-to-one-relation-in-laravel-relationship)